# What is a beton (musical instrument)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This noun appears in a song and it is clearly a instrument, but I didn't find any reference about this. The only meaning to this word is *concrete* in French.

> "The cymbals flash, the drums they crash
>   the trumpets rise the song
>   *the brass **beton** plucks its diamonds*
>   from a glittering wall of almost dawn
>   The crystal chords they slash the wind
>   in humble majesty
>   and the velvet voices all shall join
>   the singing"

Here is the complete song:

[Velvet voices by Townes Van Zandt](http://ippc2.orst.edu/coopl/lyrics/tvz_077.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the usage of the word in question was identified as a typographical error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the word that is song in the song is "baton."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening to the song, I believe he's saying, *the brass **baton** plucks bits of diamond*.  Other lyrics sites agree with that transcription.

This would be [baton](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baton).  In this song it has one of two meanings, which I feel are both realistic possibilities.

> **4** :  a slender rod with which a leader directs a band or orchestra
>   **6** :  a hollow metal rod with a weighted bulb at one or both ends that is flourished by a drum major or drum majorette

The former fits better with the orchestral theme of the song, but the latter is often reflective and designed to sparkle in the air as it is thrown or twirled.